# Price/Odds Comparision Across MYSQL Tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in a MYSQL database.

Table A

```
ID -- bfhometeam ---------- bfawayteam ----------- bfhomeodds ---------- bfawayodds
12 -- New Orleans --------- New York ------------------ 2.50 --------------------2.70
13 -- New Jersey ------- -- Boston -------------------- 1.70 ------------------- 3.40
14 -- Montreal ------------ Toronto ------------------- 1.70 ------------------- 3.40
```

Table B

```
ID -- lqhometeam ---------- lqawayteam ----------- lqhomeodds ---------- lqawayodds
17 -- New Orleans --------- New York ------------------ 2.40 --------------------2.60
18 -- New Jersey ---------- Boston -------------------- 1.90 ------------------- 3.20
19 -- Halifax ------------- Vancouver ----------------- 1.80 ------------------- 3.30
```

I want to compare the odds/prices of any matching games.

I was using this code before, but when I switched to a new server it seemed to have stopped working.

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM tableA, tableB 
        WHERE tableA.bfhometeam=tableB.lqhometeam 
           OR tableA.bfawayteam=tableB.lqawayteam";
```

I know the question is specific but I'm sure anyone making price comparison sites has encountered similar problems.

Comment: What do you mean "stopped working"?

Comment: Hmmm.. If the coalition doesn't match would that explain the error?

Comment: Tell us what error you have.  The query seem to be OK.   Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: check the names of table as they are case sensitive

Comment: @AdamB I switched to a new server, and it stopped working.  Exact same code, connecting to database correctly, just now it is showing 0 results even thought I can confirm their are matches in phpmyadmin.